# Extract a digit from a unicode string

Tags: python

I have a unicode string:

```
u'123 456 \u0320\u0111\u0333 '
```

What's the best way to extract the number from it?

Comment: `re.findall(r'\d+', string)`

Comment: no, it would turned into a different character since he defined the string as unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.findall` function.

```
>>> s = u'123 456 \u0320\u0111\u0333 '
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', s)
['123', '456']
```

OR

```
>>> [i for i in s.split() if i.isdigit()]
['123', '456']
```

Comment: the number, not the numbers, it should be "123456".

Comment: just join the list with empty string `''.join(re.findall(r'\d+', s))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the filter function:

In Python 2.*:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), u'123 456 \u0320\u0111\u0333 ')
'123456'
```

In Python 3.*:

```
>>> ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), u'123 456 \u0320\u0111\u0333 '))
'123456'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = u'123 456 \u0320\u0111\u0333 '
" ".join(re.findall('\d+', s))
```